# how to generate true or false values using normal distribution in c++

Tags: c++, boolean, distribution

I want to do that without using boost and "strange" things, I want to fill a board randomly for the game of life.

Comment: The normal distribution is continuous, so it doesn't generate true/false values.  If you're after some random values, you may just want to use rand and pick off the last bit.  Not the best random values, but good enough for this, I think.

Comment: Discretize your given normal distribution to fit into the cells of your grid.

Comment: Normal distribution is for things like height, weight (continuous). You need to be thinking of Bernoulli_distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `stlib`'s `rand()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

bool randomBool() {
  return rand() % 2 == 1;
}

int main ()
{
 /* initialize random seed: */
  srand ( time(NULL) );

/* fill up your game board here */

}
```

Just be aware that it will not yield perfectly uniform results. In order to achieve that, you'll probably have to implement something yourself. For non-cryptographic purposes, you're probably ok anyway.

Comment: Ok I know that, I will use it xDD

Comment: How is "uniform" an acceptable answer when the OP's question was for "normally" distributed points?

Comment: My teacher said this word "uniform" but googling I dont find the function to reach this

Comment: As the normal distribution is symmetric around it's median the discretization to two values of both distribution yield the same: two dirac functions with height `1/2` placed in equal distance to the median, but different from another.

Comment: Modulo is a rather heavy operator. If all rand only generates positive numbers, then the AND operator should be far more efficient. rand()&1

Comment: Modulo 2 should be replaced by bit shifting by any modern compiler.

Comment: @jupp0r A binary AND, actually, and only if the compiler can prove that the left operand is not negative (or defines `(-1)%2` as `1`). You can help the compiler with a `static_cast<unsigned>`, but it seems easier to use `&1` in this particular case. Of course, you should not *actually* use `std::rand()` and modulo or binary and, unless you care *only* about simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 12):

C++11 and do it with the following

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::bernoulli_distribution     dist;

    std::vector<bool> bv;
    bv.reserve(100);

    for(unsigned i=0; i!=100; ++i)
            bv.push_back( dist(gen));

    return 0;
}
```

Also I don't really see what the difference between uniform and normal distribution would be for a bool.

see here for C++ random numbers.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Shouldn't we seed the generator after creation? `std::mt19937 generator;
generator.seed(time(NULL));

std::bernoulli_distribution distribution;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  bool random = distribution(generator);
  std::cout << random << std::endl;
}`

Comment: Depends whether the user what a deterministic sequence or not. And if they don't then using `std::random_device` is far cleaner than `time(NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Boost isn't strange, it isn't far off being considered as standard. (in fact much of it was the backbone of new library features in the new standard -- c++11). So I wouldn't rule it out.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/normal_dist.html

Outside of a system like that, you going to have to implement it yourself which is more a mathmatics question.

Comment: +1 for recommending boost, it's an awesome library, although the OP doesn't want to use it.

Comment: I want to use it, but one day I tried to install it and doesnt works, and dont find good documentation for install & use it

Comment: @freinn it is well worth getting working, seriously. See my other answer if you have a modern compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use C++11's uniform distribution. You'll need `#include <random>`.

```
std::default_random_engine defaultRandomEngine(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> uniformDistribution(0, 1);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    std::cout << static_cast<bool>(uniformDistribution(defaultRandomEngine)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: why you can't just use  `== 1` ?